# How to get near balance of an account using cli?

Tags: nearprotocol

Is it possible to get near balance of an account using [near cli.](https://docs.near.org/docs/tools/near-cli)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running:

```
near state <account.near>
```

should do the trick:

```
Account account.near
{
  amount: 'XXXXXX',
  locked: '0',
  code_hash: 'XXXX',
  storage_usage: XX,
  storage_paid_at: 0,
  block_height: XXX,
  block_hash: 'XXXX',
  formattedAmount: 'XXXX'
}
```

or even:

```
near state account.near |  sed -n "s/.*formattedAmount: '\([^\\]*\).*'/\1/p"
```

if you just need the formattedAmount:

```
XYZ.39429240342
```

Comment: Super helpful. Thank you!